# Flex box with page break not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have my example setup in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/SpringsTea/pen/XBxNWq).
Im trying to print a dynamic amount of images in a grid in a way that things don't get cut off at the bottom of each page. usings `page-break-before` seems like the easiest way to do things.

So every 5 cols I insert a break item

`<div class="page-break"></div>`

and the following css

```
@media all {
  .page-break { display: none; }
}

@media print {
  .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

But this seems to have no effect. I can't find anywhere that explicitly states it, but since this attribute does not work with floating elements, I'm assuming it wont work with flexbox either.

How else can I achieve what I'm looking for:
Being able to create a grid 5 columns wide dynamically, from an unknown number of items, that will work with the page-break attribute.

Comment: when setting up pages for print with css, I've had to settle with specifying paper/page size and then modifying my code based on how much I can fit on the page before it overfills. And even then, depending on the browser, you will get a different interpretation of how the page will be rendered in the print preview and final print (say, pdf or paper). I assembled my pagebuilder with javascript so that I would only have the allowed number of items per page and then it would assemble another page.